# Saving models using loop on array of objects in mongoose. Need callback when all have inserted

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, csv

I need to dump a csv in mongodb. I am using the node csv plugin for this. What I do is that I generated a array of json objects by looping through rows. In the next step i plan to loop through this array and insert the documents in the collection using mongoose. I do this like:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= dataArray.length; i++) {
    var contact = new models.contact(dataArray[i]);
    contact.save(function (err) {
        console.log(i);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
                //some logic goes here
        }
    })
}
```

This works fine as far as inserting is the only concern. I need to have a callback which gets fired when all the records are inserted. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417788/how-to-populate-mongoose-with-a-large-data-set) but not convinced specially after looking at the second answer. So whats the acceptable approach for dumping a csv in mongodb with proper validations?

Comment: check this https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking here. You are **in** the callback for when the `.save()` completes. What are you trying to validate? Some more explanation in your question content please.

Answer (score 5):

Count all successful write operations:

```
var done = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= dataArray.length; i++) {
    var contact = new models.contact(dataArray[i]);
    contact.save(function (err) {
        console.log(i);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            //some logic goes here
            done++;
            if (done == dataArray.length) {
                finallyDone();
            }
        }
    })
}

finallyDone = function() {
    console.log("Everything is saved")
}
```

**Notes**:

- This does not look pretty, so maybe you should consider using a control flow library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)
- The node.js driver also allow to insert multiple documents at once, this should be a lot faster then inserting them separately.
- MongoDB ships with [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/), a tools that imports CSV directly into the database.